# Appbarlayout and scrollflags to hide one child

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-appbarlayout

I want that **child b** layout would scroll with recyclerview and hide while toolbar and **child a** would be always visible can I achieve this with only **appbarlayout** or I need to use **collapsing toolbar** for that? at the moment with code below everything scrolls up

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"
        android:theme="@style/MainActivityToolbar">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/child_a”
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap">

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/child_b”
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```